# Why I get the different group size number using pandas groupby() with or without column selection?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I try to use the numpy.size() to count the group size for the groups from pandas Dataframe groupby(), and I get strange result.

```py
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2], 'B':[1,2,3,4],'C':[0.11,0.32,0.93,0.65],'D':["This","That","How","What"]})
>>> df
   A  B     C     D
0  1  1  0.11  This
1  1  2  0.32  That
2  2  3  0.93   How
3  2  4  0.65  What
>>> df.groupby('A',as_index=False).agg(np.size)
   A  B    C  D
0  1  2  2.0  2
1  2  2  2.0  2
>>> df.groupby('A',as_index=False)['C'].agg(np.size)
   A  C
0  1  8
1  2  8
>>> df.groupby('A',as_index=False)[['C']].agg(np.size)
   A    C
0  1  2.0
1  2  2.0
>>> grouped = df.groupby('A',as_index=False)
>>> grouped['C','D'].agg(np.size)
   A    C  D
0  1  2.0  2
1  2  2.0  2
```

In the code, if we use groupby() following **['C']**, the group size is 8, equal to the correct group size * column number, that is 2 * 4;  if we use groupby() following column **[['C']] or ['C','D']**, the group size is right.

Why?

It seems that pandas try to execute the aggregation first then do the actual column selection.

Comment: How are you creating `grouped`? Also what are you expecting and what about this output is confusing you exactly?

Comment: I guess it boils down to the difference between `agg` and `apply`.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with specifying `as_index=False` combined with `np.size`. Perhaps just use `.agg('size')`

Comment: My expected output is that I can still get a DataFrame which should include column 'A' and 'C', and value of column 'C' is the group size, should be 2 in this code example. By the way, the meaning of "as_index" is whether use the groupby key as the index, why is it related to np.size?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the group size use one of these:

```
grouped.size()
grouped.agg("size)
len(grouped)
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain why Setting as_index=False makes a DataFrameGroupBy object which has 8 elements?

Comment: In this case the elements would be the index column and the C column. when you ask for the size of it you get 8. This is not what I expect pandas to do. It doesn't happen when you call multiple columns in play like grouped['C','D'], or when you call grouped['C'].size() or grouped.agg("size"). Why this case is special is not clear to me. I'll take that part out of my answer.